# Use Node.js version 16 for chaincode execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm running JavaScript/TypeScript chaincode from fabric-samples (asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript) and I need the Node.js version to be 16 instead of 12.

I think that what is setting the Node.js version to 12.16.1 is the hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv image, but I don't know how can I change it.
https://hub.docker.com/layers/fabric-nodeenv/hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv/2.4.1/images/sha256-53ec564ee28ed1fcee3be9ed1459bcc98a22fc0d81e5a707239425615641786a?context=explore

The documentation says that v2.4 modules use version 16.4.0 of Node.js and versions v2.2/2.3, 12.16.1. But I'm using the latest version of Fabric (2.4.2).
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node/blob/main/COMPATIBILITY.md

I use `./network.sh deployCC` to deploy the chaincode.

Comment: I found that the actual version of Node.js for fabric-nodeenv Docker image was recently changed, but the latest version of the image in Docker Hub is not updated.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node/commit/d9cfc3d0b35fad4ed7e72b8ced370bef32f1d0b9#diff-7d4f3937e120a0dbe6112228c21978eedc84d2c1a4a8a545808566e39bb7b0b3

The documentation states that the image can be changed with the CORE_CHAINCODE_NODE_RUNTIME env var, but I'm not sure where should the var be set. I tried doing it in the console before deploying the CC and it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by creating and uploading an updated version of fabric-nodeenv image (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node/tree/main/docker/fabric-nodeenv) and defining the CORE_CHAINCODE_NODE_RUNTIME env var in fabric-samples/test-network/compose/compose-test-net.yaml

Answer (score 0):

The official hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv docker image will be updated to use Node 16 in the upcoming v2.4.2. release.